# VB6: Retrieve stored procedure result and display string message

Tags: sql-server, vb6

I need to ask for some guidance on how to call a stored procedure from vb6 code to retrieve a set of status messages to inform the user where in the reporting process reporting is at.

The output of the store procedure is:

```
JobOrder    BatchJobTypeID  Status                                  
1           3               Previous Quarter Closed Successfully    
2           1               Reporting Quarter Opened on: Feb 14 2017
```

I know I can use a For Loop to iterate through the recordset, what I am unsure of, is how to concatenate the two separate rows containing the Status in one single line.

**UPDATE**

After seeing the first answer posted by Zohar Peled (thx). I went ahead and wrote the sub routine to accomplish this task. By taking a simple glance at it, does it look correctly?

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
    Dim con As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

    Dim strStatus As String
    strStatus = ""

    On Error GoTo errhandler

    Set con = New ADODB.Connection
    With con
        .ConnectionString = GetConnectionString("Reporting")
        .Open
    End With

    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = con
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        .CommandText = "[dbo].[DisplayJobStatus]"
    End With

    Set rs = cmd.Execute

    While Not rs.EOF
        strStatus = strStatus & rs("Status")
        rs.MoveNext
    Wend

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    con.Close
    Set con = Nothing

End Sub
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Are you really still writing new code in VB6? I am surprised that people are still using this. It has been out of support for close to 15 years now.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, we still use a few applications that were written in vb6 and are due to be migrated to a more modern technology, just not quite yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, something like this:

```vb
Dim AllStatuses As String
AllStatuses = ""
' Declare, create and open the connection and recordset code here

While Not Rs.EOF
    AllStatuses = AllStatuses & Rs("Status")
    Rs.MoveNext
Loop
' Close recordset and connection here
```